# Windows 7 shows all drives when on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ubuntu-12.04, shared-folders

I have a laptop and a desktop.  On my Desktop I have Windows 7 Pro 64 bit and I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.

In Ubuntu I setup samba, and attached myself to the network which works.

When I go to:

```
network > Windows Network > Workgroup Name > Desktop Name
```

It opens up the entire contents of the Desktop from ADMIN to all the drives created.  I did set one folder on the Desktop for sharing which shows the folder name I assigned to share.  All the other folder names show the drive letter and the folder ADMIN.  How can I limit this on the windows side to only display the shared folder as created?  In the desktop folder security I did try and remove all system rights but I was still able to access and modify content within the laptop.  When I click on each drive letter in properties > Sharing, it says not shared and Network Path: Not Shared.